Proving that a particular quotient of polynomial ring is a domain.
Let $R$ be the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at a prime $p$ and let $A = R[X,Y] / (XY^2 + p)$. I would like to prove that $A$ is a domain.
I was trying to prove $A$ is a domain by basically using the fact that the localization (over multiplicative set without $0$) and taking the polimonials over the ring preserve UFD. In doing so I am not able to use what I have studied to play with the polynomial used in the quotient.
Thanks for any input.

Hint: Apply Eisenstein's criterion to $X Y^2 + p \in R[Y][X]$ with the prime $p \in R[Y]$.

This is whay I was have in mind: I take $XY^2 + p \in (R[Y])[X]$, where the coefficients $Y^2$ and $p$ are coprime in $R[Y]$, so we can Apply Eisenstein's criterion to obtain that, since $R[Y]$ is UFD and using Gauss's Lemma (generalised), $XY^2 + p$ is irreducible in Frac(R[Y]), so also in R[Y]. Does the argument have problems? Or do you have comments?

Also, I wanted to ask if, in this case, it is correct to think that I could make the same argument working in $(R[X])[Y]$ (basically saying that $X$ and $p$ are coprime so we apply ...)

In Eisenstein's criterion, the word "coprime" does not appear. Please check again the details. And yes you can also work in $R[X][Y]$.

Thanks. I said “coprime” to justify the fact that $p$ does not divide $Y^2$, other than it satisfying the other hypothesis.

And another thing: I noticed that the conclusion I wrote is that the polynomial is irreducible in Frac$(R[Y])$, but I actually meant in Frac$(R[Y,X])$, so in $R[Y,X]$. Correct?

And to really conclude I should use the fact that also $R[Y,X]$ is UFD, so that the polynomial is also prime, then we conclude since the ideal generated is prime. Thanks for all the feed back.
